# Setup Varnish on Plesk (apache2, nginx & FPM) for Magento

Tags: apache, magento, nginx, varnish, plesk

I have a Magento 2.2.2 on a Plesk server running PHP 7.0 as FPM served by Apache2, with Nginx as the public server.

I am trying to setup Varnish for cache. The idea seemed pretty clear for me:
- change Apache2 server port
- give varnish the same old port as Apache2
- make Apache2 the backend for Varnish

This way, varnish will be the backend for Nginx, and Apache2 will be the backend for Varnish.

Still, nothing worked. Am I doing it wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have to use varnish for cache? you can try nuster, github.com/jiangwenyuan/nuster, easily achieve your requirements

Comment: `nothing worked` does not look like a valid symptom which can be addressed.
I suggest using this manual as a reference - https://www.plesk.com/blog/product-technology/varnish-wordpress-docker-container/

Comment: I did it before on this Hypernode.io: https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/varnish-on-magento2/ Hopefully relevant for you in a way :)